# Elixir/Phoenix render json on ErrorView

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to send json, when the routes don't match. From `error_view.ex`, I thing the error first hits:

```
def template_not_found(_template, assigns) do
  render "404.html", assigns
end
```

but if I change it to:

```
def template_not_found(_template, assigns) do
  %{message: "custom error"}
end
```

It doesn't actually send json, instead returns me `no function clause matching in Phoenix.Template.HTML.encode_to_iodata!/1`.
I believe this is because it expects to send some html. Is it possible to change it to send json?

My router:

```
defmodule AppWeb.Router do
  use AppWeb, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", AppWeb do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  scope "/api", AppWeb do
    pipe_through :api
  end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `config/config.exs` update the `render_error` option:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  render_errors: [view: MyApp.ErrorView,
                  format: "json",
                  accepts: ~w(json)]
```

Comment: Thank you for help! It was indeed a duplicate, I've marked accordingly.